# Accessing std::list element gets core dumped

Tags: c++, iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void runSimulation(int frameNum, fstream &fs);
void handleMemory(string address);
void handleAddress(int frameNum, string address);
void insertValue(string index);
void replaceValue(string index);
void updateOrder(list<string>::iterator orderPos);

int hit_num = 0, miss_num = 0;
const int INDEX_BITS = 5;
typedef map< string, list<string>::iterator > Memory;
typedef pair< string, list<string>::iterator > MemPair;
Memory memory;
list<string> order;

int main(){

    fstream fs;
    fs.open("trace.txt", fstream::in);

    cout <<  "LRU---"  << endl;
    cout << left << setw(10) << "size";
    cout << left << setw(15) << "miss";
    cout << left << setw(20) << "hit";
    cout << "page fault ratio" << endl;
    for(int i=256; i<=512; i*=2){
        runSimulation(i, fs);
        fs.clear();
        fs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    }

    fs.close();

    return 0;
}

void runSimulation(int frameNum, fstream &fs){
    memory.clear();
    order.clear();
    hit_num = 0;
    miss_num = 0;

    string str;
    while(getline(fs, str)){
        handleAddress(frameNum, str);
    }

    cout << left << setw(10) << frameNum;
    cout << left << setw(15) << miss_num;
    cout << left << setw(20) << hit_num;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(9) <<  (double)miss_num/(miss_num + hit_num) << endl;
}

void handleAddress(int frameNum, string address){
    string index;
    Memory::iterator found;

    index = address.substr(0, INDEX_BITS);
    found = memory.find(index);
    if(found == memory.end()){ // miss
        miss_num++;
        if(memory.size() < frameNum){ // there are empty spaces
            insertValue(index);
        }
        else{
            replaceValue(index);
        }
    }
    else{ // hit
        hit_num++;
        //cout << "hit: " << found->first << endl;
        updateOrder(found->second);
    }
}

void insertValue(string index){
    //cout << "insert: " << index << endl;
    string *newIndex = new string;
    order.push_back(index);
    list<string>::iterator it = order.end();
    it--;
    memory.insert(MemPair(index, it));
}

void replaceValue(string index){
    //cout << "replace: " << index << endl;
    memory.erase(order.front());
    order.pop_front();
    insertValue(index);
}

void updateOrder(list<string>::iterator orderPos){
    string value = *orderPos;
    order.erase(orderPos);
    order.push_back(value);
}
```

I'm trying to simulate the mechanism of Least Recently Used in OS. But I guess you could still understand the problem if you don't know about that.

The input will be a series of imaginary memory address, and they are manipulated in the form of `string` throughout the program. (I'm not talking about the address or pointer of a variable or something.) Each line contains one address, and I read them line by line using `getline`.

And there are two containers that I need to maintain all the time.
The first one is a map, whose type is `<string, list<string::iterator>>`. This 
records whether one address currently exists in the imaginary memory, and the position of the address in the list(the second container).
The second one is a list, whose type is `list<string>`. This keeps track the "recentliness" of every address. The most recent one is at the back, and the least recent one is at the front.

After getting one address, if the address hasn't exist in the map (and there still exists empty spaces in the imaginary memory), it would be first `push_back`ed into the list. Then I would record the position of that element in the list, make a `pair<string, list<string::iterator>>` (`first` is the address, `second` is the position), and `insert` it into the map.

If the imaginary memory is full, then pop the least recent one and insert the new one. Both containers should be maintained. I know which one is the least recent by accessing the front of the list.

If an address already exists in the map (a hit), the corresponding data in the list will be `erase`d and `push_back`ed into the list again, making it the most recent one.

**And here is the problem.**

While running the input, sometimes I get core dumped. gdb tells me the problem is always in `updateOrder` (I tried several different ways of rearranging codes). I suppose I didn't handle the iterator quite well.

And what's more interesting is that, If I do `runSimulation(64, fs)` it would be fine for `frameNum` to be 64, and core dumped at 128. However, if I do `runSimulation(128, fs)` first, it would be fine at 128, but dumped at 256.

Does something go wrong during initialization at the beginning of `runSimulation`? Or the iterator points to the wrong position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `updateOrder`.  You erase the existing node and create a new one, but `memory` still has an iterator to the erased node.  You could update `memory` with the new location, but a better solution is to use `splice`:

```
void updateOrder(list<string>::iterator orderPos){
    order.splice(order.back(), order, orderpos);
}
```

This will move the existing node to the end of the list without invalidating any existing iterators.

Incidentally, you leak memory in `insertValue` when you allocate a string (that you don't use).

Comment: Oh wow I forgot to consider that. Thank you so much. Now it works.